# VB.Net Adding References Programmatically

Tags: vb.net, dll

I am fairly new to VB.Net. I have written some code which successfully performs a purpose on my own machine. However, the code requires reachframework and it is going to be ran within some banking CRM software which irritatingly; really locks down a lot of functionality. Unfortunately this includes the project>add>reference functionality found in visual studio.

I have looked for a day or so trying to see how I could add my reference library reachframework.dll programatically and then use the contents of its namespaces but have had no luck.

I noticed that the references appear to be declared within the XML .vbproj file I do not have access to modify this file within the CRM software either - so that hacky "solution" (whether modifying it manually would have worked or not I don't know) - is out of the question

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so how I would go about it?

Comment: how does a CRM system prevent you from adding references in visual studio?

Comment: If you can't add reference, or modify the XML file then u can't.

Comment: it is pretty much a glorified textbox where I can put vb.net code and then I have a build button which I believe creates the executable which the software then references. These are assumptions based on observation as the providers of the CRM software aren't terribly forthcoming with this kind of information. There are other workarounds I can think of (hosting it outside the CRM) but that isn't ideal. Thank you both.

Comment: Is [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.Assembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) an option?

Comment: You need to add references to an assembly at compile-time. You can use reflection, as helrich suggested, though you begin to run into security issues. If the super-basic compiler in the CRM doesn't support adding references, then reflection is your only choice. If you run into security issues (reflection requires very high "trust"), then there's no way to accomplish this from within the CRM.

Comment: I think that requires an extension, so I would need a way to add an extension programatically which I think presents a similar problem?

Comment: If you can't even get namespaces in `System` then this is pretty much a lost cause. That CRM sounds like a lot of fun...